# sort list of lists based on third element and return the two first element

Tags: prolog

How to sort list of lists consisting of `[[A,B,2000],[C,D,2008],[F,G,2004]]`
based on last element in each list and return the first two element as in the example above. That is `[[A,B],[F,G],[C,D]]`.

Comment: Lots of ideas, but you need to show an attempt at something.

Comment: i does not know how start please help

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no this is part of my work on project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that words that start with a capital are variables, not atoms. It's unclear from the problem statement whether it's intended that the list elements are variables. I'll assume that they are variables, as it won't impact the proposed solution.

There are probably a number of ways to do this, but here's one method which I won't claim is the optimum way:

1) Use `setof` to collect the sorted values in a different order. That is, collect your list as a new list that looks like this: `[[2000,A,B],[2004,F,G],[2008,C,D]]`. This assumes that each list item is unique (no desired duplicates).

2) Write a simple predicate that goes through the new list and strips off the first element of each sublist.

The final solution would look like:

```
process( L, Result ) :-
    setof([Z,X,Y], member([X,Y,Z], L), SortL),  % gives list like shown above
    stripyear(SortL, Result).
```

`stripyear` is the predicate that would go through each list item and strip off the year (the first element of each sublist). It is very simple and follows basic Prolog list processing principles:

```
stripyear([[_,B,C]|T1], [[B,C]|T2]) :-...
```

Here the head of the main clause says that if my input is a list that looks like `[[_,B,C]|T1]`, then the output is a list that looks like `[[B,C]|T2]`. That is, the second lists's head is the head of the first list with its first element removed. We don't care what that element is in value, so we use `_` to show it. But then we need to deal with `T1` and `T2`. How are they related? I've already taken care of the head. The tails are recursively related the same way: The tail of the second list is the tail of the first list with the year (first sublist element) removed: `stripyear(T1, T2)`. So the full main clause looks like:

```
stripyear([[_,B,C]|T1], [[B,C]|T2]) :- stripyear(T1, T2).
```

That's great but how does it stop? And what if I had an empty list (`striplist([], ?)`)? The list `[]` doesn't match `[[_,B,C]|T1]` because it has no head or tail. It's empty. And without a clause to deal with it, `striplist([], Result)` would fail. So I need a clause to handle it separately, which also concludes the recursion:

```
stripyear([], []).
```

This says that if I strip the years from the empty list, I get an empty list. Very logical.

Comment: i try but i didn't know how to write stripyear?

Comment: @user3141061 can you show your attempt? Hint: `stripyear([[_,B,C]|T1], [[B,C]|T2]) :- ...`  would be the main case and you need a base case as well for the empty list. You fill in `...`.

Comment: stripyear(SortL, Result):-
append([T],result).

Comment: @user3141061 one problem with your attempt is that `append` requires 3 parameters. This is clearly described in the documentation for `append`. Also, you didn't define `T`, and it's very unclear how `append` helps you here. Have you gone through any Prolog tutorials or sample problems? `stripyear` is very simple in Prolog and follows very fundamental list processing principles.

Comment: i am stuck at this point.

Comment: i didn't know how to keep track of list??

Comment: stripyear([[_,B,C]|T1], [[B,C]|T2]) :-
stripyear([], [[B,C]|T2]).
is this good base case.?

Comment: @user3141061 that's the head of the clause, but you need to fill in the body, which would describe how `T1` and `T2` are related. Yours shows `T2`. What happened to `T1`? And the head of the clause already takes care of `[B,C]` so why is it showing up in the clause body? I would highly recommend working through the prolog problems given here, which also shows solutions:  are related. Your example only shows `T2`. What happened to `T1`?

Comment: i am under that i need T1 be as output but i didn't how it wrote?

Comment: `T1` isn't an output. It's an input in this case. It's the tail of the input list. `T2` is the tail of the output list. How are these related?  If you don't have any idea at all how list processing works, then I suggest working through these prolog problems, and the solution are given: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2009s2/prolog/problemas/. You have to learn to walk before you can run. :)

Comment: i am learn prolog ,i need copy T1 to output list but i did not know how?

Comment: @user3141061 you don't want to copy it. That's why we have `T2`. If we copied, we'd have `stripyear([[_,B,C]|T1], [[B,C]|T1]) :-...` but that would copy over the years as well, and you don't want that. You want the years stripped out! So you have to strip the years from `T1` giving `T2`. See my updated answer.

Comment: if i need to strip the year without sort how to do this?

Comment: @user3141061 just think about it a bit. Look at the pattern of `stripyear` and modify it. It currently assumes the year is the first value, so it uses `[_,B,C]` and changes that to `[B,C]`. If you just want to strip the year from the unsorted list, what would those look like?